# What is a good way to implement a search functionality if querying large amounts of data?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a web page built for documentation library purposes. I want to implement a search engine to it that works kind of like Google Search; something that would return to the user relevant information for their query, even if they had minor misspellings and such.

There are a few libraries and external services out there from what I discovered, like lunr.js or Elastisearch. I'm not a fan of using an external service since that might bring up security concerns (correct me if I am wrong of course).

I'm aware this is more of a general question, but I am in need of some advice for an approach to this. Thank you.

Comment: One of (less sophisticated) possibilities is to build a Binary Search Tree (BST) for your entire dictionary. Then, given a word (potentially misspelled one) you will be able to identify at least the closest word from your dictionary. By checking parent you can find a range of words closest to the input (see BST implementation).

Comment: Uh, neither lunr.js nor elasticsearch are external services?

Comment: I know lunr.js is not but if that is so, then I might've misunderstood what elasticsearch actually is. Apologies for my ignorance on the topic.

Comment: @ataerena See https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch, especially the part on "*What are the options for deploying Elasticsearch?*". They might advertise their cloud offerings more aggressively than the on-premise version, but most people install and manage the service on their own.

Comment: @Bergi Looking into it now, thank you for your time!